# Option on dropdown as anchor

Tags: php

I am pulling out record from the database and inserting them inside a dropdown like this:

```
echo "<select>";
while ($drow = mysql_fetch_assoc($request))
{
   echo "<option>" . $drow['id'] . "</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
```

It works but I need to be able to click on an option on the dropdown and make it link just like:

```
<a href="Record1Here">Record1Here</a>
<a href="Record2Here">Record2Here</a>
<a href="Record3Here">Record3Here</a>
```

UPDATE: Latest code:

```
<script>

function doSomething() {
    var currentval = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
    // you could navigate away at that point ?
    window.location = currentval;
}
</script>

...

echo "<select onchange='doSomething();'>";
while ($drow = mysql_fetch_assoc($request))
{

   echo "<option value=\"view.php\">" . $drow['id'] . "</option>";

}
echo "</select>";
```

Comment: Is that even possible with HTML?

Comment: @h00ligan: It's not. You need JavaScript.

Comment: Also, for OP. I don't recommend you doing it this way. Have a submit button and relocate the user properly. It's unexpected from a select input to redirect the page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't place anchors on an option within a select list.

What you can do is use JavaScript and then do something on the `change` event of the select list :

```
echo "<select onchange='doSomething(this);>';
```

then in JavaScript do something based on the selected value :

```
function doSomething(elem) {
    var currentval = elem.options[elem.selectedIndex].value;
    // you could navigate away at that point ?
    window.location = currentval;
}
```

[Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/rnWrN/)

you could update your PHP code to include a value in each `option` :

```
echo "<option value=\"urlhere.php\">" . $drow['id'] . "</option>";
```

Comment: Tested this but onchange my url gets "undefined" added to it

Comment: @Satch3000 updated the first line of the `doSomething` function - try that

Comment: tested that change but does nothing at all now

Comment: @Satch3000 please update your question with **all** of the updates you made then I will take another look

Comment: Updated the question with the latest changes

Comment: @Satch3000 OK - couple of changes ... see my updated answer and example ... `onchange` needs to send `this` and the `doSomething` function slightly changed